# How to create an end date field in a hook_form_alter

Tags: datetime, forms

I've succeeded creating a simple date_popup field with the following code :

```
$form['date_start'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('Start date'),
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
);
```

Now, is there any way to directly create the "End date" field without having to create a second field declaration ? Is there any bundled widget I can use ? I've seen something about date_combo but I'm not sure to understand it well.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2):

there is no way to do it with the standard field widgets, you have to craft your own, the examples module may help you

Comment: this may help you https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_widget/7